The Hanf number of higher-order logic
The reduction of second-order logic (SOL) to a $\Pi_1^1$-fragment on the Stanford Page of Higher-Order Logic (Section 4) is as follows:

From this we get that the Hanf and Löwenheim number of SOL is the same as a $\Pi_1^1$-fragment of SOL (the Hanf number of SOL is also the supremum of $\Sigma_2$-definable ordinals). The intuition behind this being that already at the level $\Pi_1^1 \cup \Sigma_1^1$ there is enough expressive power to express any second-order property.
Something of key interest is that this notion of expressing second-order properties (with extra predicates) can be extended so that $\Pi_1^1$-formula can also express any property of higher-order logic ($n^{th}$-order logic for $2 \leq n < \omega$). An implication of this result is that SOL has the same Hanf and Löwenheim number as HOL (as well as having Turing equivalent decision problems). A very interesting result about the expressive power of higher-order logics later mentioned in section 12.
I'm trying to understand the full picture of how they get this result as this isn't exactly explained why on the Stanford page, but I believe it is connected to a result of Hintikka 1955 (this document contains two papers from Hintikka, the second paper discusses this, pg., 57 - 115). Mainly, Hintikka showed that any formula K of the theory of types (equivalent to HOL) will have a translation $\xi$ (K) within second-order function calculus that is equisatisfiable. That is, any statement of HOL will have an equisatisfiable statement in SOL.
I believe Hintikka's result is somehow connected due to showing a relationship between sentences of SOL and HOL and have been attempting to connect it to the result on the Stanford page. So why can any statement of HOL be 'expressed' as $\Pi_1^1$-statement? Does it utilize Hintikka's result and how so exactly?

Edit: After further research, the general strategy is to  1) apply Hintikka’s equisatisfiability result, ‘reducing’ a higher-order sentence to a sentence of SOL 2) we are then able to reduce it to the level of $\Pi_1^1 \cup \Sigma_1^1$ ,this is somewhat discussed by Montague 1963 (p.g., 251-264, key points are lemma 2 and theorem 1), where they are reduced to a second-order formula $\psi$ containing no predicate variables of more than two places (this has some sort of equivalence to a $\Pi_1^1$ - formula but I am unsure exactly how).
My problem then is that is equisatisfiability a strong enough property for a sufficient reduction? It seems to me that this would require some sort of logical equivalence (which is a stronger property).

See this old answer of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3717344/28111. (That answer only sketches the proof of the result you're asking about, so I don't want to unilaterally mark this question a duplicate in case you want more details, but the idea is indeed there.)

@NoahSchweber Your answer in that post is definitely on the right track, especially discussing Turing equivalent decision problems. I want more details about how a sentence of HOL can be expressed by $\Pi_1^1$ sentence (particularly how the result in the Stanford page is extended to include HOL) and if Hintikka's result is incorporated (since it shows a sort of 'reduction' to second-order). I haven't found any papers discussing this.

First off, to clarify equisatisfiability. A sentence $\phi$ of higher-order logic is equisatisfiable to a sentence $\psi$ of second-order logic means that $\phi$ is satisfied by a model of higher-order logic (in this case $n^{th}$-order logic for n>2) if and only if $\psi$ is satisfied by some model of second-order languages. Key point is that equisatisfiability is a connection between a pair of sentences in which satisfiability is preserved no matter the language or logic. We will now move on to the key results of Hintikka(1955) which are integral to answering this question (note: Hintikka's paper uses outdated notation and mathematical notions due to being from 1955, I will try my best to translate).
Note: D is a constant formula of the second-order functional calculus and $\xi(K)$ is the translation of K into a formula of the second-order functional calculus (this translation follows certain rules which is a lot to list here although they can be seen on pages 99). The formula $\chi(K)$ is defined as follows

Let K be any formula of the theory of types. The formula $\chi(K)$ denotes the formula
($T_{\tau_1}(\xi (q_1^{\tau_1})) \land ... \land T_{\tau_\kappa}(\xi (q_\kappa^{\tau_\kappa}))$ 
of the second-order functional calculus, where $q_1^{\tau_1} \land ... \land q_\kappa^{\tau_\kappa}$ are all constants of K, $\tau_1 ... \tau_\kappa$ are typed variables of levels 1 to $\kappa$ (correpond to a domain in the type-theoretic hierarchy of universes).

The following are key results of the paper that show a translation from a formula of the theory of types to one of second-order functional calculus, preserving satisfiability and validity (p.g., 100-101)

THEOREM III: A formula K of the theory of types is valid (that is, K is true in all models of the theory of types) if and only if ($D \land \chi(K)) \supset \xi(K)$ is valid.  
THEOREM IV: K is logically false (not true in any model of the theory of types) if and only if ($D \land \chi(K)) \supset \neg \xi(K)$ is valid.

These two formulas together imply that for K is closed, K is valid if and only if ($D \supset \xi(K)$) is valid and that K is logically false if and only if ($D \supset \neg \xi(K)$) is valid.
There is a further reduction to a second-order monadic formula (i.e., a formula with unary predicates) found on page 113 and which preserves satisfiability.

THEOREM V: A formula of the form X(L) (where X is a monadic predicate variable and L a formula of the first-order functional calculus) is satisfiable in the standard sense if and only if it has a general model set $\mu$ with the following properties


i) Each member of $\mu$ satisfies one of the following conditions with respect to {(X)L}

a) L is a subformula of a formula satisfied by a standard model set v
b) L is a negation of a subformula of a formula satisfied by v
c) L is an atomic formula whose proper symbols all have a type less 'complicated' than the type of some variable occurring in a formula satisfied by v
d) L is an identity whose constant satisfy the same condition as in c)



ii) $\mu$ /{(X)L} $\cup$ {($\exists$ X) $\neg$L} has no general model set, all the individual constants of which occur in the formulae satisfied by $\mu$

The notion of a 'general model set' closely resembles the notion of 'model' used in usual model theory since 'non-standard' models are allowed. The notion of 'standard model set' as described in the paper is more restrictive (and a further restrictive model is considered, called a 'strong model set').
In the Standford page of higher-order logic the key is to reduce monadic second-order formulas $\phi$ over $U^{\mathfrak{M}}$ (which we have obtained via THEOREM V) to a first-order formula $\phi^{*}$ over M. We can then obtain a $\Pi_1^1$ -formula involving $\phi^{*}$ and extra second-order predicates which expresses the monadic second-order formula. Since we have initially reduced a higher-order sentence to a second-order one and then to a monadic second-order formula in which satisfiability is preserved, then $\Pi_1^1$ - formulas can express properties of higher-order and non-monadic second-order logic (satisfiability is sufficient since Hanf numbers are a global property which doesn't care for meaning/semantics to be preserved). Applying the latter part of the Standford result then you get that the Hanf and Löwenheim number of higher-order logic is the same as second-order logic which is the same as a $\Pi_1^1$ -fragment.
Related posts: Are higher order logics substantially stronger than second order and Is n+1
-th order logic always more expressive than n
-th order logic? (see Noah Schweber's answer)
